# count and group by in mongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, aggregation-framework

I have a mongo collection system and its document structure is like this

```
{
    "_id" : "some id",
    "created_datetime" : ISODate("2013-06-08T21:36:15.173Z"),
    "installs" : [
        {
            "country" : "ZA",
            "install_datetime" : ISODate("2013-06-08T21:36:15.173Z"),
            "package_name" : package_name1
            "status" : 1,
        }
    ],
}
```

I want to get the total installs for each "country" for each "package_name" for "install_date" > July-24-2013, some what like a group by query in MySQL. I am a newbie to mongo Aggregators, and really dont have idea how to write mongo aggregator queries

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The aggregation operator you are interested in is [`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/unwind/), which will allow you to pass the installs into a [`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/group/) operator, on whichever of the `country`, `package_name`, or `install_date` fields that you are interested in.

Once you've done the `$unwind` your have a `$group` query will look something like:

```
{ $group : {
    _id : "$country",
    installPerCountry : { $sum : 1 }
}}
```